# What is a better approach of implementing android FCM push notification?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a scenario while using FCM push notification for Android app.

Consider my app structure is like (Sign-up & Login screen are part of splash screen, so only mentioning Login in below example)

```
Login => A 
Login => A => B 
Login => A => B => E
Login => A => B => C 
Login => A => B => C => E
Login => A => B => C => D
```

Now I can receive a push notification which can be about C or B only.

In the FCM Push notification there are 2 case that can happen
1, app is running
2. app is not running

case 1. 
App is running in foreground, I can redirect the user to C or B as per push notification. And when I press back button, my previous activity comes to foreground.
Here if my app is in Recent App list, and I tap on notification, it directly goes to activity C or B. and on pressing back button the activity is destroyed, but I can't redirect user to activity A. How do I achieve it?

Here is How I have handled my FCM notification

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        dataPayload = remoteMessage.getData();

        Intent intent = null;
        if (dataPayload.has("detail")) {
            intent = new Intent(this, C.activity);
            intent.putExtra("details",dataPayload.getString("details"));
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(this, B.activity);
        }
        sendNotification(intent)
    }
}

private void sendNotification(Intent nwIntent) {
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, nwIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Case 2.
App is not running in background. In this case FCM notification handles the intent and starts the app  but doesn't redirect to particular activity C or B. 
So here first Login screen will Appear and then activity A.

How can I redirect user to C or B activity without loading activity A? On which life-cycle method of activity A,  I required to handle Intents so activity A doesn't make any call to web api for data but directly redirect to activity C or B and when I press back button it should redirect to A?

Comment: Can't you use Intent flags to clear A from the Activity stack?

Comment: @cricket_007 if you are talking about `case 2`. then I don't want user to wait for let activity A is loaded and then got to C or B. why  ...because in `case 1` if user taps on notification then it directly goes to C or B even if any activity is foreground or app is in `Recent App` list. so to keep the same user experience I am trying to achieve the same with `case 2` also.

Comment: @cricket_007 I did....

Comment: Is the A Activity loaded because you've registered  it in the manifest to receive the notification?

Comment: A activity is loaded because as I mention in my app structure is like (Sign-up & Login screen are part of splash screen) so App starts with splash screen and after splash the default activity I have to load is A.

Comment: Is there a way you can bypass the splash screen when you get a notification? Or is that not the question you're asking ?

Comment: In case 2 where push notification isn't created by my java code but the the system creates it,  because my app is not running - not even in background . So, if user taps on THAT notification, system will launch the default intent of the app, and that is the splash screen. In case 1 I can by pass splash screen and directly load C or B activity.

Comment: Any one ?!?!?!?!?